# browser stack for 2d buildings display and navigation

Tags: javascript, graphics, webgl

I'm developing a 2D web app for showing buildings and features therein.

I want to zoom down to circa 1:500 scale; the site is approx. 300 by 300 meters.

I have great DWGs of the site, a separate DWG for each floor plan. [image: image of floor pan approx 1:500 scale]I want to use this drawing as a background, and plot features on top of it. There would be approx. total max 1000 features, but max 200 shown at any one time.

From the DWGs I have made PDFs and DXFs. The file sizes are big - DWG circa 6MB, pdf 1.8MB, DXF 40MB.

I want to develop the fastest experience for users, whether they have phones, tablets, or desktop PCs.

I tried a `canvas` approach using a pdf similar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607526/zoom-on-simple-pdf-js-viewer), but the app crashed when I attempted to zoom in to 1:500

One option is to use web-mapping such as `openlayers` with `geoserver` serving e.g. `WMS` tiles, i.e. georeference the DWG (or a derived DXF) and convert to a format that could be served as tiles for the background, then map the features atop that.

But I'm wondering if there might be other faster and/or simpler approaches, maybe using two.js (or even three.js)?

I don't need animation or 3D, but thought a `webgl` framework might be a better approach than web mapping?